# MySQL query not taking advantage of index

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I was analizing a query (working on a wordpress plugin named nextgen gallery), this is what I got

query:

```
EXPLAIN
      SELECT title, filename 
        FROM wp_ngg_pictures wnp 
   LEFT JOIN wp_ngg_gallery wng 
          ON wng.gid = wnp.galleryid 
    GROUP BY wnp.galleryid 
       LIMIT 5
```

result:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                   | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wnp   | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                  |  439 | Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wng   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | web1db1.wnp.galleryid |    1 |                                 | 
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

so I do:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_ngg_pictures ADD INDEX(galleryid);
```

and on my local test system I get:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+--------------------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref                | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+--------------------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wnp   | index  | galleryid     | galleryid | 8       | NULL               |   30 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wng   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 8       | test.wnp.galleryid |    1 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+--------------------+------+-------+
```

which seems fine, but on the final server I get

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref                   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wnp   | index  | galleryid     | galleryid | 8       | NULL                  |  439 |       | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wng   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 8       | web1db1.wnp.galleryid |    1 |       | 
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------+------+-------+
```

so the index is used but all the rows are scanned anyway? Why is this happening?

Only difference I can see is mysql version which is 5.1.47 (local) vs 5.0.45 (remote), data is the same on both systems.

Comment: Is the content of the tables of your test and live system the same? Just a guess: On your test system you have only 30 entries in the wnp table, so it also looks at every row, too. - With a left join it looks at every row of the left table.

Comment: The content is exactly the same, I used a backup of those tables.

Comment: Sry, no idea. My understanding is, a left join returns all values of the left table, even if there are no matches on the right. So I don't understand your query :-)

Answer (score 0):

The *rows* column in the EXPLAIN SELECT output is an estimate of the number of rows that MySQL believes it must examine to execute the query, so I guess it is possible that your local version (5.1.47) is better at estimating than your remote version.

Without the EXPLAIN clause, do both queries produce the same output?  What happens if you change the query to use a STRAIGHT_JOIN?

Comment: Yes the queries produce the same output and the type of JOIN doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I believe that MySQL may use previously gathered statistics when it calculates the results for an EXPLAIN SELECT.  You could try running "ANALYZE TABLE wp_ngg_pictures" on both servers, and then re-issue the EXPLAIN SELECT statement.

Comment: Another thought - does removing the LIMIT clause change the outcome?